# Parsing and comparing strings on Arduino: different behaviour from gcc?

Tags: arduino-ide, teensy

I am trying to parse a simple string, print the result of the parsing via serial.println, and trigger a function on the basis of the received command. I wrote the code below, which perfectly works in c (see the c file attached). However, the behaviour of the same code on the arduino IDE is completely different and I really can't figure out why.

```cpp
#include <string.h>

void rcv_msg(char *rcv_msg) {

  char *all_tokens[2]; 
  int i = 0;

  all_tokens[i] = strtok(rcv_msg, "{,}");
  while (all_tokens[i] != NULL) {
    all_tokens[++i] = strtok(NULL, "{,}");
  }

  char *command = all_tokens[0]; 
  char *value = all_tokens[1];


  /*
  //These printls do not work, they are ignored, why?
  Serial.println("all_tokens[0]: ");
  Serial.println(all_tokens[0]);
  Serial.println("all_tokens[1]: ");
  Serial.println(all_tokens[1]);
  */

  if (strcmp(command,"message_1") == 0 && strcmp(value,"1") == 0) {

    Serial.println("message 1: ");
    Serial.println(command);
    Serial.println(value);
    Serial.println(" ");

  }

  if (strcmp(command,"message_2") == 0 && strcmp(value,"0") == 0) {

    Serial.println("message 2: ");
    Serial.println(command);
    Serial.println(value);
    Serial.println(" ");

  }
}



void setup() {

    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {

    char msg1[] = "{message_1,1}";
    char msg2[] = "{message_2,0}";

    Serial.println("Send msg1: ");
    rcv_msg(msg1); 
    delay(5000);

    Serial.println("Send msg2: ");
    rcv_msg(msg2); 
    delay(5000);    
}
```

This code gives the following output on the serial monitor, which is wrong:

Send msg2: 
message 2: 
message_2
{message_2,0}

Send msg1: 
message 2: 
message_1
{message_2,0}

Send msg2: 
message 2: 
message_2
{message_2,0}

Send msg1: 
message 2: 
message_1
{message_2,0}

Firstly, I don't understand why at the beginning, message 2 is printed before message 1, although message 1 was sent first. Second it is not clear to me the comparison done with strcmp is always returning the message 2.

More importantly, why running the same code in c has instead the correct output? I wonder if there is any error in my arduino code. BTW, I am testing the code on Teensy 3.2 but I plan to use it also on Arduino Uno.

The c code (which is perfectly working is this:

```cpp
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void rcv_msg(char *rcv_msg) {

    char *all_tokens[2]; //NOTE: the message is composed by 2 tokens: command and value
    int i = 0;


    all_tokens[i] = strtok(rcv_msg, "{, }");
    while (all_tokens[i] != NULL) {
        all_tokens[++i] = strtok(NULL, "{, }");
    }

    printf("all_tokens[0] : %s \n", all_tokens[0]);
    printf("all_tokens[1] : %s \n", all_tokens[1]);

    char *command = all_tokens[0];
    char *value = all_tokens[1];

    printf("command : %s \n", command);
    printf("value : %s \n", value);



    if (strcmp(command,"message_1") == 0 && strcmp(value,"1") == 0) {
        printf("activating command : %s %s \n\n\n", command, value);
    }

    if (strcmp(command,"message_2") == 0 && strcmp(value,"0") == 0) {
        printf("activating command : %s %s \n\n\n", command, value);
    }
}



int main() {

    char msg1[] = "{message_1, 1}";
    char msg2[] = "{message_2, 0}";

    rcv_msg(msg1);
    rcv_msg(msg2);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions of your code have undefined behavior. On the given input your code will call `strtok` *three times* and store its result into the array *three times*: for the first token, for the second token and, finally, for the null pointer. You store all three (including that null pointer!) into the `all_tokens` array, which has size `2`.

You are obviously aware of the potential array overrun danger: you even wrote this comment in your code

```
char *all_tokens[2]; //NOTE: the message is composed by 2 tokens: command and value
```

and yet in the following cycle

```
int i = 0;

all_tokens[i] = strtok(rcv_msg, "{, }");
while (all_tokens[i] != NULL) {
    all_tokens[++i] = strtok(NULL, "{, }");
}
```

you still insist on storing more than two values into `all_tokens` array.

---

Also, the second version of your code uses completely different message key values (why is it suddenly `"motor1_pattern1"` instead of `"message_1"`?), which makes it unclear how you compared the functionality of the second version with the functionality of the first.

Comment: many thanks. I added while (i < 2 && all_tokens != NULL)  which solved the problem. Is this the best way of doing it? Also I edited the code removing motor1_pattern with message_1 (sorry that was a bad copy-paste I did).  I still wonder:
Why the serial monitor still displays first the second message although the first message was sent. It seems that the first message does not reach the serial monitor... what I am missing?
Finally, do you suggest to use strtok_r instead of strtok?

Comment: Suggest to have a look at the message about memory usage while compiling. Arduino have only a small amount of RAM and string functions are using a lot. If your code is very small, it can work, but the more you'll increase the size of code and the more you'll get strange results.